# Is there another name for a vector?

Tags: terminology, vectors

I am writing a program uses contains both vectors (direction and magnitude) and vectors (a matrix with one row/column) and my head is spinning. I could replace the latter kind of vector with oneDimensionalMatrix (but I'd rather not because that is long winded too unintelligible) so I was just looking to see if you guys knew of any synonyms, my online thesaurus of choice did not give math-y answers.

P.S. this is my first time here and I wasn't sure if this belonged here or on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) but I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and I didn't find anything saying I couldn't ask a math vocab question, but if I missed something please point me in the right direction.

P.P.S.
also, couldn't find a tag that suited this post so if someone could recommend one that would be good.

Comment: Row and column matrix

Comment: I'm curious about why you want to distinguish between the two, because they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"row_vector", "column_vector" (or shortenings) would be appropriate for the matrix version. "arrow" would be appropriate for the direction/magnitude version.

Answer (score 1):

A vector, as you say, is best thought of as a free-floating arrow -- a geometric thing that has direction and magnitude, but no fixed position. If you choose a fixed basis (i.e. a fixed coordinate system), then you can represent any vector by its three components with respect to this basis. You could call this collection of three numbers a "triple" or a "tuple". If you want to distinguish tuples of different lengths, you could use "Tuple2", "Tuple3", etc.

If you switch coordinate systems, the vector will not change but the components will. So, a vector and its tuple of components are not the same thing. However, as long as you're using a single fixed coordinate system, you can identify them without getting into too much trouble.